# How to find all couples of trades that happened in the range of 10 seconds

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to find all couples of trades that happened in the range of 10 seconds, with prices differing by more than 10% & result set shall include percentage of price diff between the 2 trades.

Table Creation:

```
create table Trades 
(TRADE_ID varchar(max), TIMESTAMP time(0), SECURITY varchar(max), QUANTITY int, PRICE int
);

Insert into Trades values
('TRADE1','10:01:05','BP',100,20),
('TRADE2','10:01:06','BP',20,15),
('TRADE3','10:10:00','BP',-100,19),
('TRADE4','10:10:01','BP',-300,19),
('TRADE5','10:01:08','BP',150,30),
('TRADE6','10:01:09','BP',300,32);
```

Expected Output:

```
First_Trade Second_Trade    PRICE_DIFF
TRADE1      TRADE2          25
TRADE1      TRADE5          50
TRADE1      TRADE6          60
TRADE2      TRADE5          100
TRADE2      TRADE6          113
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use `exists`:

```
select t1.price, t2.price, (t1.price - t2.price) * 100.00 / t1.price
from trades t1 join
     trades t2
     on t2.timestamp >= t1.timestamp and
        t2.timestamp < dateadd(second, 10, t1.timestamp) and
        t2.tradeid <> t1.tradeid and
        t2.price not between 0.9 * t1.price and 1.1 * t1.price
```